# Xcode shows no error but the react native app crashes forced close automatically right after the splash screen showed

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am developing an android app with react native. It is successful and already uploaded on play store. Now I am trying to build it in iOS version, but when I am opening the simulator, the app crashed, only splash screen that showed up and then forced close automatically. There is no any error showed in terminal in xcode. I am using macbook air M1 and xcode 14.2. Do you know why that happened and how to fix it? Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using any custom splash screen plugins? Please share your package.json file. Also app.js file

Comment: No, I am not using any custom splash screen. after i click the app, the screen is on like 1 second then forced close with no error log on console. here is the package.json and app.js that you asked https://pastebin.com/WGWBUzFJ

Comment: Can you try disabling the firebase part and check once?

Comment: I tried that at first, but didn't work. now i just created new project and copy paste the code to it. It works, with lots of error still of course, but I can see the error message in the console or in the simulator which is better than nothing.

Comment: Can you check your build scheme? I have updated my answer. Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your  **Build Configuration** for Run is "**Debug**" and not "Production"

Inside Xcode. Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

Attaching screenshot for reference

[image]

Comment: i tried that but its empty, there is nothing in console.